# Internal server error with UpdateItem EWS call from Mail Addin

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using makeEwsRequestAsync to issue an UpdateItem call on an email I just made a copy of through another makeEwsRequestAsync  I used with CopyItem.  However, the response for UpdateItem is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">*</Action></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInternalServerError</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInternalServerError</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.</e:Message></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Any ideas? Below is the call I'm making.  My goal is to create a copy of an email, change the subject line and recipient and send it (to emulate doing a forward).  What's odd is that my call to UpdateItem doesn't even occur when I run the Mail Addin in OWA, but it works in Outlook 2016.  I'll ignore that for now lol

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'               xmlns:t='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'>  <soap:Header>     <t:RequestServerVersion Version='Exchange2013'/>  </soap:Header>  <soap:Body>'<UpdateItem MessageDisposition='SaveOnly' ConflictResolution='AutoResolve' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'> <ItemChanges> <t:ItemChange> <t:ItemId Id='AAMkADk0OGI2NTc3LTZkY2QtNDc1NS05MWM1LTZlNmRhMjQ4MjRlMABGAAAAAACRc/2u6ZxxTKKnN1SuVEBWBwCiPid+VwI1QKpXdMXuhotWAAAAAAEMAACiPid+VwI1QKpXdMXuhotWAADwH8K3AAA=' ChangeKey='CQAAABYAAACiPid+VwI1QKpXdMXuhotWAADvtGmZ'/> <t:Updates> <t:SetItemField> <t:FieldURI FieldURI='item:Subject'/> <t:Message> <t:Subject>UPDATED SUBJECT</t:Subject> </t:Message> </t:SetItemField> </t:Updates> </t:ItemChange> </ItemChanges> </UpdateItem>   </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one problem with your XML you have an extra ' in (between Body and UpdateItem)

`<soap:Body>'<UpdateItem MessageDisposition='SaveOnly'`

With that removed your request work okays for me, you should make sure you have the latest changekey and the Item your trying to update should be located in the Mailbox where the AddIn is running

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Oh good grief! Thanks Glen! I'm finally delving deeper into EWS after all these years, and I was actually scanning your blog last week to help get me up to date. Good stuff!

Comment: @Glen how to validate the XML SOAP request beforehand in Javascript? Just getting "internal server error" doesn't help at all to try to find the bug.

Comment: If you can find a library that will validate you XML against the WSDL that might work I've not used any myself, personally i use the EWSEditor which has a folder with XML examples and also a simple query form you can submit a test SOAP request against. It can be quite difficult to spot error in XML this way i start with a working request and then just do comparisons until i find the error which is time consuming but I haven't found a better way when debugging raw SOAP. One issue is Microsoft actually broke their online docs (by changing http to https) a year ago this should all be fixed now